# PyTorch .to(torch.device("cuda")) speed differs vastly depending on execution state - How to achieve a speed up?

Tags: python, pytorch

My question is concerned with the speed of the [`to`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to) Method of PyTorch tensors and how it depends on the "execution state" (not sure if thats the correct name, feel free to edit).

My setup is as follows (RTX 2060 Super):

```
python version: 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]
pytorch version: 1.7.0+cu110
```

Firstly, a file that contains the code for what I'm talking about:

```python
import torch
import time
import sys

gpu = torch.device("cuda")

def ver():
    print("python version:", sys.version)
    print("pytorch version:", torch.__version__)
    print("\n")

def test():
    start = time.time()
    torch.cuda.init()
    print("cuda init:", time.time()-start) 
    x = torch.randn(15000,3).float()
    print("randn initialized:", time.time()-start)
    x.to(gpu)
    print("to(gpu):", time.time()-start)
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    print("time after sync:", time.time()-start)
    print("\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ver()
    test()
    test()
```

Running this yields following console output:

```
python version: 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
pytorch version: 1.7.0+cu110


cuda init: 0.002934694290161133
randn initialized: 0.0033266544342041016
to(gpu): 1.5724568367004395
time after sync: 1.5725233554840088


cuda init: 9.5367431640625e-07
randn initialized: 0.00030875205993652344
to(gpu): 0.00037860870361328125
time after sync: 0.00039458274841308594
```

The speed of the second `to` call is so much faster than the first one. Why does this occur?
And more importantly, how can I achieve consistently fast speeds? 
In a bigger project I'm working on I should have enough time to maybe initalize the GPU in parallel before `to` gets called for the first time. Is that possible? If so, how? `torch.cuda.init()` doesn't seem to change the speed of the first `to`.

I cannot use `torch.randn(x,y, device=gpu)` because in the original setup the data comes from `torch.from_numpy()`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first run is always the slowest because it is loading everything on to the gpu. After the first run the times get much more consistent. If you run your test a few more times you should see the times are much closer to each other.

Comment: I understand that loading onto the gpu takes time. But the second run initializes a new torch.randn tensor and also needs to move it onto the gpu. I would completely agree with your statement if I would reuse the tensor. So why is there a difference in load times with different tensors?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I'm pretty sure it is still the same thing. When you first run cuda you are initializing it so it takes longer to load on your tensor. After the first run however cuda is already started and it just needs to load tensors to the gpu.

Comment: Alright. Any idea why using torch.cuda.initiliaze() beforehand doesn't increase performance?

Comment: I'm not sure looking at the documentation for that command it seems that you do not need it for python. I don't think it is helpful for ordinary users. Or at least that is what the documentation says.